# Does a forbidden door stop thieves?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I currently have a set-up in my fortress involving a small entrance filled with traps and a trade depot connected to a moat with a drawbridge. I have an alternative entrance to the depot from within my fortress, so that I can restock while the bridge is up.

The alternative entrance has one gap in which I have placed a door. Now I'm wondering, if I forbid that door, will this stop thieves?

Likewise, I'd also like to know if I link this door up to a lever so that is it open when the drawbridge is up, can thieves open a mechanism-closed door?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [wiki](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Defense_guide#Doors_.28.26_Hatches.29), "Most creatures will be stopped by any door or hatch, though some others can smash them...You can forbid doors to keep (most) hostile humanoids and creatures out, and your dwarves in."

Doors should stop <strike>ordinary goblin thieves</strike> and most "ordinary" creatures, like mandrills.
Creatures that can break down a door are going to be more interested in smashing than stealing.

EDIT: The comment is correct. [This](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Snatcher) article clarifies that goblin snatchers can, in fact, bypass locked doors, but not floodgates, or anything similar that's secured with mechanisms and lever. Animal thieves *are* stopped by locked doors.

Comment: Actually I thought thieves and baby snatchers were not stopped by doors.  That's why you want to chain two war dogs inside your doors.

Comment: do note that you can control doors with levers too, which gives them the same features and disadvanages as a floodgate.